# How to +1 to the digit if the first decimal is greater than or equal to 5?

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, rounding

My goal is to add the value in front of my decimal place when the first decimal places is more than or equal to 5.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float num = 0.5222f;

    cout << (int)num << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

My intended result is 1 instead of 0. How should I modify the code to get the expected result?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to round this value to the nearest integer, you could just add `0.5` before casting it to int:

```
float num = 0.5222f;
cout << (int)(num + 0.5);
```

or alternatively you might use one of the following functions from the `<cmath>` header:

```
double      round  (double x);
float       roundf (float x);
long double roundl (long double x);
```

Comment: The first method will fail in implementations in which the range of an `int` does not extend to the value converted from `float`. It is better to use the `round` routine that is expressly designed for this function and that does not change types.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: `num + 0.5` will yield result of type `double` because of `0.5` literal... you're trying to point out the case where the result of this addition will be larger than largest possible value storable as `int` ?

Comment: Consider `float num = 0x1p31;` in a typical C implementation where `int` is 32 bits or `float num = 32768;` in a C implementation where `int` is 16 bits (not so common this days but still reasonable in small systems). And there is simply no need for this; there is no need to use `int` at all for this operation.

Comment: I am using VS2012 ultimate update 3 and there is no round C++11 feature in the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

In *C++11* we now have [std::round](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round), so this would work fine:

```
std::cout << std::round(num) << std::endl;
```

would also need to include `<cmath>`. The non-*C++11* method using [floor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor):

```
std::cout << floor(num + 0.5) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cast a `float` to an `int` it rounds towards zero, dropping the fractional portion of the number.

What you want to do is call `roundf` first. (`round` for double, `roundf` for float)

```
cout << (int)roundf(num) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add:

```
float num = 0.5222f;
cout << std::floor(num + 0.5);
```

In this way you can even decide to round up also if (say) first digit is > 3

```
float num = 0.3222f;
cout << std::floor(num + 0.7);
```

Don't know how much useful, but.... you can!

Answer (score -2):

Try the ceil function.
It rounds up numbers of 0.5 to a whole decimal number by 1.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil

Comment: That would output 2 for 1.1

Comment: I guess its wrong then my brain clicked fast with this one. Maybe he just didn't explain the problem that well but this is exactly what he wants to do?. I dont know.

Comment: You can round up, down, or conditionally based on the input. Ceiling, floor, and round are the three most common (corresponding, with the condition being >= 0.5 for up and < 0.5 for down). There are also other schemes like towards zero/away from zero, and banker's.